# In which Yuga did Shiva destroy Tripura?

Tags: shiva, puranas, yuga, manvantara

In two days we will be celebrating Dev Deepawali. I want to know in which Yuga and which Manvantar did Shiva destroy the three citadels of Tripura? Is the information mentioned in any Puranas?

Comment: That's important question because it was a major battle discussed in the puranas. I post a similar question here https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/33204/12-major-battles-between-the-devas-and-danavas

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to Keshav, we have some bounds on the chronology of this event.

1. Lower bound
   In regard to the destruction of Tripura, the three Asura brothers who ruled Tripura were sons of Tarakasura, whom Kartikeya killed, and they built Tripura after the death of their father. But Kartikeya did not kill Tarakasura until Muchukunda fought Tarakasura. So the destruction of Tripura happened some time after Muchukunda’s time as king. Muchukunda was the son of Vishnu’s incarnation Mandhata who was born in the 15th Mahayuga of the Vaivasvata Manvantara.
2. Upper bound
   the Valmiki Ramayana describes the destruction of Tripura as having happened in the past. So the upper bound would be 24th Mahayuga.

It would be great if some Lord Shiva bhaktas can help us solve this puzzle. 
Also interestingly, Lord Shiva got the name Pasupati in this pastime so this is a very significant pastime.

Comment: another interesting thing which could help is that Lord Parasurama came in the 19th Mahayuga. If anyone knows any connection of Tripura war with Lord Parasurama

Comment: You should cite sources.