# Timelines for 12 major battles between the Devas and Danavas

Tags: vishnu, puranas, bhagavata-purana, narasimha

Many Puranas talk about 12 major battles between the Danavas and Devas. As per Brahmanda Purana (3rd Canto, Ch 72), they are as follows:

1. Lord Narasimha fighting the Danavas
2. Lord Vamana binding the Bali
3. Lord Varah fighting Hiranyaksha
4. Battle after churning of the ocean: Prahlada defeated in the battle.
5. Tarakamaya battle: Kalanemi killed by Krishna
6. Adibaka battle: Jambha killed by Visnu
7. Traipura battle: Daityas defeated by Lord Siva
8. Andhakara battle
9. Dhvaja battle: Vipracitti was killed by Mahendra.
10. Vrtra battle: Vrtrasura killed by Indra
11. Halahala battle
12. Kolahala battle
    13? Sanda and Marka conquered by Devas [even though there should be 12, 13 are mentioned :-0]

Link for english translation of Brahmanda Purana: https://archive.org/details/24BrahmandaPurana.Vol.3/page/n203

Now here is my question what are dates for these battles?

> Few I know from another question asked on the stackexchange
>   [During what Yugas did Hiranyakashipu, Mahabali, and Ravana rule?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/18211/during-what-yugas-did-hiranyakashipu-mahabali-and-ravana-rule/33182#33182)
>
> 1. Lord Narasimha deva appeared in Chaksusa Manvantara 4th Kali & 5th Satya transition.
> 2. Lord Vamana appeared in 7th Treta yuga of Vaivasvata Manvantara.
> 3. Lord Varaha appeared right in the beginning of Chaksusa Manvantara

As per Srimad Bhagavatam 6.10.16 http://vedabase.com/sb/6/10/16

> 10.Vrtrasura defeated by Indra in the the beginning of First Catur Yuga at the onset of Treta Yuga during the Vaivasvata manvantara.

As per Padma Purana I.40.122-123

> 5. Tarakamaya war happened in a Satya yuga after Vrtrasura was killed.

Comment: Nice list! Thanks for the question hope someone can answer this.

Comment: My understanding is that these events (at least the ones I am familiar with) took place on a different "plane" of existence. For example Svarga is not outer space and Patala & Naraka aren't literally in the Earth's crust. They are different lokas; different "realities." We only experience 3 dimensions of space and 1 dimension of time, so we can be called 3+1D beings. But there is the possibility of 4+1D, 5+1D, 3+2D, 5+3D, etc beings. So, if an event is not part of the material realm we experience as Earthlings, then how can we put a date on it?

Comment: @rubellite ,The dating would be using the (n-space, m-time) system of Yuga, Manvantara. Answer needs quotes from scripture.

Comment: @ajitdas AFAIK Yuga, Manvantara is only describes time & ordinality. It doesn't describe space (so IDK why you brought up n-space) or other potential dimensions (which would explain why there are no scriptural references to their temporal position). There is no possible answer because the question makes a categorical error in posing it, from what I can tell. For example, "How many apples is an orange?" is a question without an answer because of the categorical error the question presumes.

Comment: Abt n space- since we humans have not comprehended the space where the Gods dwell. m-time because there are time cycles in sequence. Agree that it's not m dimensional time i meant. Though m dimensional time may exist, speculating randomly.